# I'm trying to symulate casinos version of War

Tags: bash

This script will be used in a lot greater project which will in theory simulate very famous casino game WAR. Unfortunately I am receiving some completely which craft results whenever this script is executed.In theory I should receive one integer either 1 or -1 which will tell me if I won or not, unfortunately I get 2 or even three integers for some odd reason.

```
#!/bin/bash
# play a game from one position
function matchOne {
score=0;
# set dealer Card
dealer=$((RANDOM%13+1));
# set player Card
player=$((RANDOM%13+1));
#if dealer won
if [ $dealer -gt $player ]
then
score= expr $score - 1;
#if player won
elif [ $player -gt $dealer ]
then
score= expr $score + 1;
# if their's a tie
elif [ $player -eq $dealer ]
then
matchOne
fi
echo $score
}
#execute function
matchOne
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the following two immediate issues:

1. `expr` not only evaluates the expression, but also writes the results to standard output. What you're trying to achieve can be rewritten as:

   ```
   score=$((score-1));

   # or maybe just
   score=-1;
   ```
2. In case the two values are equal, your `echo` statement will get called multiple times. You need to rethink your logic.

**Update**

Just removing the `echo` statement would also solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, I've made changes which you recommended but now all I get are bunch of 0's

Comment: Which changes? Removed `echo` statement? Or the first set of changes?

Comment: #!/bin/bash

#play a game from one position
function matchOne {
score=0;
# set dealer Card
dealer=$((RANDOM%13+1));
# set player Card
player=$((RANDOM%13+1));
#if dealer won
if [ $dealer -gt $player ]
then
score=$((score-1));
echo $score
#if player won
elif [ $player -gt $dealer ]
then
score=$((score+1));
echo $score
# if their's a tie
elif [ $player -eq $dealer ]
then
matchOne
fi
}
score=0;
# attempt 1,000,000 times
for i in {1..1000000}
do
score=$((score+matchOne));
echo $score
echo $score >> something.txt
done

Comment: You've mixed my first set of proposed changes with the change I proposed in the update. It's either-or.